# Behaviour when merging branches at different points in collaborative Git

Tags: git

Imagine Tim and and Rob are both working on separate Git branches (`tims-branch` and `robs-branch`), that have both branched off a development branch (`develop`).

Now, imagine Rob needs Tim to add something (Tim is responsible for back-end, Rob is responsible for front-end and needs a new api endpoint adding).

If Tim checked out `develop` and created a new branch (`api-endpoint`) and added this new api endpoint, then Rob could easily merge these changes into `robs-branch` with a `git merge api-endpoint`.

However, if Tim didn't checkout `develop` and instead created this `api-endpoint` branch off `tims-branch` which was further ahead of `develop` (i.e. had a lot of new stuff Tim was working on), and THEN Rob tried to merge it in would:

1. This be ok because `api-endpoint` only contains the new data that Tim added for Rob anyway.
2. Rob would not only get the new code that he wanted, but also everything else from `tims-branch` because `api-endpoint` came out of that branch.
3. The entire internet would break.
4. Something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Rob would not only get the new code that he wanted, but also everything else from `tims-branch` because `api-endpoint` came out of
>      that branch.

Tim could try to fix this by doing an interactive rebase of `api-endpoint` that removed all of the commits that came from `tims-branch` after it diverged from `develop`.  While in the `api-endpoint` branch

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

Where N should be a number, greater than or equal to the number of commits it would take to get back to `develop`.

Tim might have to resolve conflicts and continue the rebase a couple of times, but then `api-endpoint` should be mergeable for Rob in the intended way.

Comment: `git rebase -i develop` also works, so you don't have to count the number of commits since develop.

Comment: I presume the best and most common solution is to just branch off develop (and switch between branches if there is anything that is needed to be copied across?)